# MySQL query not filling table with values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a booking calendar, but am having an issue with my 'addactivity' form. The basic logic is that for each date/time a new activity object is created and calls the function toDataBase which then takes the info from the form and puts it into the database. I've stripped out all of the foreach and other logic. Here's the relevant code.

from the form method:

```
$name=$_POST['activityname'];
$cost=$_POST['activitycost'];
$spaces=$_POST['activityspaces'];
$venue=$_POST['activityvenue'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$day=$_POST['day'];
$dates[$count]=date('Y-m-d', mktime($month,$day,$year))
$time=$_POST['activitytime'];
```

and the toDataBase function

```
public function toDataBase()
{
    $dbc=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$db);
    if(!$dbc)
    {
        echo ("could not connect".mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt=mysqli_prepare($dbc, "INSERT INTO events(
    name,
    date,
    venue,
    cost,
    spaces,
    time) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sssiis',$event_name,$dates,$price,$max_spaces,$venue,$times);
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);



}
```

what confuses me most is that I don't get a MySQL error of any sort. I know the activity object's data fields are filling because I have methods for each datafield to echo its value. All fields are filling just fine but aren't going into the DB. My next assumption was that the db is expecting values of a different type. The event table structure is as follows:

```
name: varchar
date: date
venue: varchar
cost: smallint
spaces: smallint
time: varchar
```

Sorry for the wall of text, but I'm getting frustrated banging my head against aforementioned wall of text.

edited: switched to better practice: still same issue.

Comment: $dates is an array, and you're trying to substitute it directly into the string?  Try echoing $query to see what you are trying to execute.  And then learn about parameterised queries before you release a hackable system...

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, kind of new so haven't really learned the "best practices".

Comment: Sounds like you need to un-learn `mysql_query` as soon as possible before you cause serious damage.

Comment: In the process of that now. What's the best type specification for a date value?

Comment: @Dems $dates is an array of (what I assume are) strings and I am taking the value at one index of the array and using it. I wouldn't have thought that would cause an issue?

Comment: Anything in the php error log?

Comment: Are the columns in the table called (name,    date,    venue,    cost,    spaces,    time)? definitely? some of those are key words. but are you certain theyre spelled exactly that way in your database?

Comment: Your date will need to be mysql compliant: '2000-12-31'

Comment: @case1352, yes they are called with spelling case correct. Date is being output in YYYYmmdd format... just doesn't seem to love me enough to go in. Gonna try on another server in case the issue lies there

Comment: try it with just like one field at a time

Answer (score 0):

After some serious zen finding, I realized that $event_name etc were private variables... simply changed to $this->event_name and all worked fine. Thanks for the help anyway people. At least my code isn't (as) exploitable now =)